# How to get updated GitHub project after merge?

Tags: git, github

I have a quick question about GitHub (workflow). I just started using it so this question might seem naive.

1) Say I have a local project which I created a branch and committed my changes.

2) I push up my changes to my GitHub Repository.

3) I then create a Pull request to a member who is going to review my work.

4) He accepts the work and merges my branch with his master copy.

My question is, how do I get those changes to my project? I am confused on how to update my project by using his since he merged it to his master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So let's say you worked on a feature and your branch is called "1420"
after your colleague accepted your work and merged with master

**He should push master branch to server, and then you have to branch out from master to begin with a new feature.**

Steps:

1. Checkout to master branch.

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Make sure your local master branch have the latest changes from
   server by pulling all the changes.

   ```
   git pull
   ```

*(by now you have all your changes)*

---

Additional steps to start a new feature:

3. Create a new branch from master for the new feature which will consist of your old branch 1420 commits and master commits (make sure you are in master branch) and then.

   ```
   git checkout -b 1421
   ```
4. By now you should have all your changes and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still a bit confused. When you say " He should push master branch to server" is he pushing it to His gitHub account or somehow to mine?  All I want is when he merges my branch to his master, I would like to update my master branch to be up to date

Comment: I updated the answer please let me know you got the point now :)

Comment: Clear this up. Do I and my collaborator have to share the same GitHub Account for this to work this way? You keep mentioning pushing to server but is he pushing to HIS GitHub account or to a account we are Sharing?

Comment: No. Once the guy pushes the changes to server by "git push -u origin master" his changes will be on server. Now, all you have to do is step 1 and 2 and you should have the changes.

Comment: ooo so if he pushes the Changes to his GitHub account to Master and I do a Git Pull somehow Those changes he accepted which are part of his master will update my master copy? Thanks for the help I am learning this stuff all today!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122587/discussion-between-johncarp-and-abzoozy).